# SQL query doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller

In phpMyAdmin this SQL query works fine

```
SELECT products.id FROM products, characteristics 
                WHERE products.id = characteristics.pr_id AND products.c_id = 1
                AND characteristics.value IN ('8-core', 'Quad-Core') 
                AND price BETWEEN 50 AND 5000 GROUP BY products.id
```

But when I try to make it work in my Model, it fails.

```
$products = DB::select('SELECT products.id FROM products, characteristics 
        WHERE products.id = characteristics.pr_id AND products.c_id = ?
        AND characteristics.value IN (?) 
        AND price BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY products.id', [$catId, $query, $minPrice, $maxPrice]); 
dd($products);
```

PS: if in Model I will work with only one parametr in `$query`(e.g. 'Quad-Core') everything works fine. But as soon as I try to work with several parameters, I get empty array.

Controller

```
$values = Input::get('value');
$category = Input::get('cat');
$brand = Input::get('brand');
$minPrice = Input::get('min_price');
$maxPrice = Input::get('max_price');
$query = implode('", "', $values);

$product = new Product();
$products = $product->getProductsByPar($query, $minPrice, $maxPrice, $category, $brand);
```

Model

```
public function getProductsByPar($query, $minPrice, $maxPrice, $cat, $brand)
{
    $category = new Category();
    $brands = new Brand();
    $minPrice = (int)$minPrice;
    $maxPrice = (int)$maxPrice;
    $catId = $category->getCategoryId($cat)->id;

    if($brand == 'none')
    {
    $products = DB::select('SELECT products.id FROM products, characteristics 
            WHERE products.id = characteristics.pr_id AND products.c_id = ?
            AND characteristics.value IN (?) 
            AND price BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY products.id', [$catId, $query, $minPrice, $maxPrice]);            
    }
    else
    {
    $brandId = $brands->getBrandId($brand)->id;
    $products = DB::select('SELECT products.id FROM products, characteristics 
            WHERE products.id = characteristics.pr_id AND products.c_id = ?
            AND products.b_id = ? AND characteristics.value IN (?) 
            AND price BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY products.id', [$catId, $brandId, $query, $minPrice, $maxPrice]);             
    }
    dd($products);
    return $products;
```

What do I do wrong about query in Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Laravel [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries).

```
// Prepare parameters
$categoryId = 1;
$values = ['8-core', 'Quad-Core'];
$minPrice = 50;
$maxPrice = 5000;

$products = DB::table('products')
    ->select('products.id, characteristics.*')
    ->join('characteristics', 'products.id', '=', 'characteristics.pr_id')
    ->where('products.c_id', $categoryId)
    ->whereIn('characteristics.value', $values)
    ->whereBetween('products.price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I usually use query builder, but I thought that it would be better to make it that way. And with your idea everything works fine, since `$values` can be array and it will work with laravel query builder

Comment: Sometimes Laravel's query builder is more hinderance than help, but on this occasion the query is pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `in` in prepared statement, and you can't do this.

Your question is being evaluated as:

```
characteristics.value IN ("'8-core', 'Quad-Core'")
```

And it doesn't really makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't with `in`. You will need to find some other solution for this.

Comment: But if I do `$query = implode('", "', $values);`, then it should be evaluated as `characteristics.value IN ("8-core", "Quad-Core")`

Comment: No, because `$query` is a string, so if you do `IN(?)` you actually have `IN("$query")`

Comment: yeah, but after `implode` it looks like `8-core", "Quad-Core`. So when it's called in query, it should become `"8-core", "Quad-Core"`

Comment: It only looks like it, but it is still a string